# Initialize OpenMP in C code

Tags: c, openmp

The structure of my program is like:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int ...
float ...

/*initialize OpenMP*/
#ifdef _OPENMP
    omp_init();
#endif
...
forloop(<parameters>);
exit (0);
}
```

forloop.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif
void forloop(<parameters>)
{
...
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) \
    private(...) \
    shared(...)
#endif
for (i=0;i<n;i++){...}
}
```

I initialize OpenMP in `main.c` using:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    omp_init();
#endif
```

But the OpenMP parallel code is in `forloop.c` rather than in `main.c`. Do I have to initialize OpenMP again in `forloop.c`?

Comment: No, just once is ok.

Comment: What is `omp_init`? It is not in the standard - neither the headers or libraries from gcc and intel compiler know this.

Comment: Many compilers insert openmp initialization code in main() when compiled for OpenMP parallel.  As noted above, there's no portable way nor need to call it.